# Flattening out a Group Membership Tree in SQL (with Cyclic references)

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am working with a table of goups.

GroupMembers (GroupName, MemberName)

There is a row present for every group member and a group can contain other groups and users.

I would like to extract a list of GroupName, MemberName pairs where the MemberName is only a list of users. Essentially, flattening out the tree. I have done something similar to this before and manually wrote queries which exported each level's leafs out to a seperate table and then consolidated this once I had reached the last level.

The tree appears to be unbalanced and does not have any fixed number of levels. I have been looking at examples of recursive queries, and have not had much luck in implementing them.

Does anyone have any good pointers on where I can go to put togeather an elegant solution to this?

Many Thanks!

ps If it helps, I am working with SQL Server 2008.

**UPDATE: I stumbled upon Recursive CTE. My only issue is that there are Cyclic references in the data :(.**

This the code I used for the query:-

```
    WITH Members AS
    (
    --Init
    SELECT GroupName, MemberName
    FROM GroupMembers
    WHERE MemberName NOT IN (Select GroupName from GroupMembers)
    UNION ALL

    --Recursive Exe
    SELECT h.GroupName, h.MemberName
    FROM GroupMembers h INNER JOIN Members m
    ON h.MemberName = m.GroupName
    )
    Select * into GroupMembersFlattened from Members OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1500)
```

Is there a way to exclude the cyclic references/clense the data prior to execution of the above query?

Thanks!

**Example Cyclic/Circular Reference**
An example of a Cyclic reference would be where the data contains the following:-

```
    GroupMember,     MemberName
    Group1,     Group2
    Group1,     User1
    Group2,     Group3
    Group2,     User2
    Group3,     Group1
```

Thanks for the tip Mikael!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide some sample input data with a cyclic reference and what the expected output should be.

Comment: So, in the above example, groups 1, 2 and 3 should be treated as the same group, right? And both `User1` and `User2` should belong to all `Group1`, `Group2` and `Group3` ?

Comment: Hey JP, I am just winging this, but could you define your select as distinct? I'm not sure, but that might stop the recursion. Just a thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you exclude the cycles

```
WITH Members AS
(
--Anchor
SELECT 
    GroupName, 
    MemberName,
    0 As isCycle,
    '.' + CAST(MemberName As varchar(max)) + '.' As [path]
FROM GroupMembers
WHERE 
    MemberName NOT IN (Select GroupName from GroupMembers)

UNION ALL

--Recursive call
SELECT 
    h.GroupName, 
    h.MemberName,
    CASE WHEN m.[path] like  '%.' + CAST(h.MemberName as varchar(max)) + '.%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END As isCycle,
    m.[path] + CAST(h.MemberName as varchar(max)) + '.' As [path]
FROM GroupMembers h 
    JOIN Members m
        ON h.MemberName = m.GroupName
WHERE
    m.isCycle = 0
)
SELECT  
    * 
FROM 
    Members
WHERE
    Members.isCycle = 0
```

Comment: Hello Magnus, Thanks for your response. I implemented your solution and it worked like a charm. I used the Path field to extract the Name of the User and GroupName for the Parent Group at the top of the tree. Again, many thanks for your input and thanks for such a quick response.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to extract a list of
>   GroupName, MemberName pairs where the
>   MemberName is only a list of users.

I probably don't understand your structure here but to me it looks like you only need to do this.

```
SELECT GroupName, MemberName
FROM GroupMembers
WHERE MemberName NOT IN (Select GroupName from GroupMembers)
```

This will give you all the leaf nodes. If a group can be a leaf or if a user can have members you need something else to distinguish between users and groups.

Result with your sample data:

```
GroupName   MemberName
---------   ----------
Group1      User1
Group2      User2
```

Comment: Hello Mikael, thanks for your reply. The issue I had was that I needed a list of Parent Groups from the top of the tree and then their expanded lists of leaf users. I can see where you are going with the suggestion, but I think it would only work if the nesting was 1 level deep. After using Magnus's solution I found that the neseting varied from 1 level to 8 levels deep in my data. Thanks for your input though, it's much appreciated.